# Strangely large processing size in BigQuery query on partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have just noticed some strange processing size behavior while running BigQuery queries on a Timestamp-partitioned table. We have a table with about 70 devices streaming inserts once per minute, so about 70 inserts/minute or 4,200 inserts/hour. Showing a small example is the easiest way to describe the problem. In the BigQuery UI on GCP, if I query one day of data:

```
select * from dataset.table where DATE(time) = '2020-09-21';
```

it says

> This query will process 3.2 GB when run.

However, if I query 7 days of data:

```
select * from dataset.table where DATE(time) >= '2020-09-15' and DATE(time) <= '2020-09-21';
```

it says

> This query will process 3.3 GB when run.

Through some experimentation, I found that there is about 14 MB increase in processing size for each day, which I expect is the true size of each partition.

What is even stranger is that this extra space seems to grow exponentially with the size of the table. As an example, I created a new table containing only 10 of the 70 devices and added a few months of data from these devices. When I performed these queries, I found that the query processed 1.4 MB for a 1-day query, and 8.9 MB for a 7-day query, which is an increase of about 1.07 MB/day, meaning this "extra size" is only about 33 KB, or about 2,300x smaller than the table with all devices.

So my question is what is this large extra processing size and why is it there? There must be something related to streaming inserts or caching or **something** that I'm missing?

Comment: do you also have clustering field on that table?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you sure your table is partitioned on the `time` field and not on the `_PARTITIONTIME` pseudo-field? It sounds like your query isn't taking advantage of partitions so I could see this be one reason.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant There is no clustering, but I did find something intriguing in Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables#clustering_partitioned_tables) on Clustering. "In a partitioned table, data is stored in physical blocks, each of which holds one partition of data. ... This requires BigQuery to maintain more metadata than an unpartitioned table. As the number of partitions increases, the amount of metadata overhead increases." We have almost 3 years of data, so ~1,000 partitions.

Comment: @rtenha Yes it partitioned by our "time" column and is verified in the UI. Also, the amount of data processed increases with the number of days queried.